# loop until a certain condition is met

Tags: c++, while-loop

From this site https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lca-for-general-or-n-ary-trees-sparse-matrix-dp-approach-onlogn-ologn/
I have a problem with this while loop part:

```
// runs till path 1 & path 2 mathches 
int i = 0; 
while (path[1][i] == path[2][i]) 
    i++;
```

I want to increment i until two array elements are equal and I expected this loop to be like:

```
// runs till path 1 & path 2 mathches 
int i = 0; 
while (path[1][i] != path[2][i]) 
    i++;
```

because I want to increment "i" when values are not equal but it does not seem so. Why equality is checked instead of inequality? This while loop confuses my mind. (Note: I run the whole code and it is working.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the line which follows (in your reference) where the last matching is returned, I see it that the error is in the comment. It should say something like "runs as long as the paths match" not "till".

Comment: at 1st while loop check, path[1][0] is not equal to path[2][0] so loop should not be executed and i should not be incremented even one time. Isn't this true?